# laravel eloquent query relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relation

I want to load events based on `city_id` saved in `locations` table.

These are my tables:

EVENTS TABLE:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('event_name');
$table->integer('event_location_id')->unsigned();
```

LOCATIONS TABLE:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('location_name');  
$table->integer('city_id')->unsigned();
```

In my events model I have:

```
public function locations()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Locations','event_location_id');
}
```

and in my location model :

```
public function city()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('City','city_id');
}
```

How to obtain events based on city?

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the relation locations you do it this way

```
City::find($id)->locations
```

if you want to get the names you need to iterate through it

Answer (score 0):

Classic `hasManyThrough` example:

I assume model names: `Event`, `Location`, `City`

```
// City model
public function events()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough('Event', 'Location', 'city_id', 'event_location_id');
}

// then simply
$city->events; // Collection of Event models
```

it will return all `Event` models related to all `Location` models of given city.

Read http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships